# Why Facebook application id suddenly become invalid?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

First of all I'm sure that my fb app id is valid because users can log in my Android app using facebook credentials until some days ago (I think it's before Feb break change).

Recently new users cannot log in my Android app using facebook any more because facebook keep saying that my fb app invalid (Error is: `Invalid application fb-app-id`) BUT `old users` who already authorized my Android app for accessing their info can still log in using facebook. (Old users can still login to my app using facebook credentials  but new users cannot)

Does anyone know why this happen to my facebook app and how to fix it?

Edit: When access to https://graph.facebook.com/facebook-app-id I get this error

```
{
"error": {
  "message": "Unsupported get request.",
  "type": "GraphMethodException",
  "code": 100
    }
   }
```

Thanks you.

Comment: Did you perhaps set your application to sandbox mode?

Comment: No, sandbox mode is off, my old users can still using facebook to log in to my app.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're sure the app is not in sandbox mode (which was gema.megantara's answer), and hasn't been deleted for policy reasons by Facebook the only explanation I can think of is that you've restricted the app demographically (i.e by country or age)

If that's the case the API won't return the app's details unless you make the API call using a user access token for a user who meets whatever restrictions you've applied, and users who don't meet the requirements won't be able to use the app.

If that's what you've done, you can remove the restrictions via the API (via the `restrictions` field of the [Application object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/) or in the ''Advanced'' tab in the app settings in the [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)

If using the frontend interface to change the settings, it's the ''App Restrictions'' field you want to edit, screenshot attached [image: settings interface]

Comment: Thank you, I will check and let you know if that is the case or not.

Comment: It seems that problem resolved after I remove country restrictions. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

Basically the same solution as the accepted answer, just updated for the latest FB developer site has been updated so you need do this:

1. Apps->Your App
2. Status+Review
3. Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? -> Yes

[image: updated]

Answer (score 5):

Usually if you get error like that when visit https://graph.facebook.com/523132271032907 is because the sandbox mode is on. Have you try to reset the secret key ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, what page?

Comment: Sorry my bad, before i wrong read your question. I edited my answer.

Comment: Sandbox mode is off. Why do you suggest me to reset the secret key :D?

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is because FB does not check whether application id is valid when the user has already logged in. It likely assumes that if the check passed, the id *is* valid. Apparently, locking out the users after making the app id invalid has never been a design goal.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing:

`<string name="facebook_app_id">CHANGE-ME</string>`

with:

`<string name="facebook_application_id">CHANGE-ME</string>`