# LikeView Not Working using Android facebook app

Tags: android, facebook

I am using likeview in android app

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_underconstruction);

        // Get LikeView button
        LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.likeview);
        likeView.setEnabled(true);
        likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.BOX_COUNT);
        // Set the object for which you want to get likes from your users (Photo, Link or even your FB Fan page)
        likeView.setObjectIdAndType("https://www.facebook.com/ekashmir.in", LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
        // Set foreground color fpr Like count text
        likeView.setForegroundColor(-256);

}
```

In android AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />


<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderMY_APP_ID"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
android:value="@string/app_name" />
```

I am facing 2 issues:

1) When i click on likeview button, every thing works fine but with developer account only

2) Total Number Of Likes Does Not Appear In Like Buttons.

Please Help

Comment: When i click on likeview button, every thing works fine but with developer account only this problem occurs when your facebook applicationID not in live as public..

Comment: refer answer 3 screenshort will be there..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019625/why-facebook-application-id-suddenly-become-invalid

Comment: @sasikumar my facebook app is live, but my app is not on play store yet!

Comment: Its not problem,if you sure facebook application is in live, then check other part of code

Answer (score 1):

Add your manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
android:value="@string/app_name" />
```

Full details  refer [Here](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-add-facebook-like-button-in-android-app/en) and [LikeView](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LikeView)

Answer (score 0):

I leave this here as an update because likeview as described above, will not be supported as of 02/06/2018.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/

> Native Like Button: The Native Like Button, designed for mobile apps, will no longer be supported starting with Facebook SDK version 4.28 and above. Previous versions of the SDK can still use the Native Like Button, but starting 2/6, the Native Like Button will no longer be supported. After 2/6, the dialogs for Native Like will no longer appear and taps on any native like button will result in no action.

Comment: but i am using 4.0.1. still it is not working.But login is possible