# Error when login with Facebook in Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-graph-api

I came across with an unknown error while login with Facebook in my app.
The error coming recently before that I could successfully do login with Facebook.

And I didn't change any thing in my code.

On Button click-
here is the code:-

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email,user_birthday"));
```

here is the Facebook login manager code:-

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mFBCallbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
//on success code here
}
```

I attached the screenshot of the error coming on login.

[image]

Any help will appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any such restrictions configured in your app dashboard?

Comment: No ,I didn't configured such restrictions.

Comment: @ShoebSiddique [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019625/why-facebook-application-id-suddenly-become-invalid). Check Apps->Settings->Advanced->App Restrications.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH ,
I check it,didn't configured such restriction.

Comment: @ShoebSiddique this error occured after entering login credentials or not ask for credentials?

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH the error occurred  after entering login credentials

Comment: @ShoebSiddique Ok try with other login credentials maybe restrict from your fb account settings. Or remove the app from your fb account and reinstall app in device and try again.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH I try to login with different credentials but error remain same.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue in in *user_birthday* permission it requires app review now so either remove this permission or submit an app for review. See this blog post for more information https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/07/02/app-review-deadlines-approaching/

Comment: Asking for non-reviewed permissions should show a totally different error message. (And to people with a role in the app only, for normal users it will just be silently ignored.)

Comment: I remove user_birthday permission, still getting the same error.